# High memory usage reported in Running Services

Tags: android, memory-management

I've seen that my background service is allocating 25Mbs according to the Running Services android window.
As it is a lot of memory that I think I don't use I looked to ddms and also made a head dump of my process and then the memory usage is only 2.9Mb

What's is the real memory usage?
If it is the ddms one is there any way to let running services give the correct usage? Because I'm afraid that if some user look at the running services it will say that the application is wasting a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that android memory heap doesn't contain native memory like memory from bitmaps, or webview. Then the real memory usage is the one from background services. You can also retrive it from:

`adb shell dumpsys meminfo`

More detailed description in  [that discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7018aaa1e1413ebd)